# Regular Expression Phone Number Validation

Tags: javascript, regex, vb.net

I wrote this regular expression for the Lebanese phone number basically it should start with

**00961** or **+961** which is the **international code**  then the **area code** which

could be either any digit from **0** to **9** or cellular code **"70"** or **"76"** or

**"79"** then a **6** digit number **exactly**

I have coded the following **reg ex** without the 6 digit part :

`^(([0][0]|[+])([9][6][1])([0-9]{1}|[7][0]|[7][1]|[7][6]|[7][8]))$`

when i want to add code to ensure only 6 digits more are allowed to the expression:

`^(([0][0]|[+])([9][6][1])([0-9]{1}|[7][0]|[7][1]|[7][6]|[7][8])([0-9]{6}))$`

It Seems to accept 5 or 6  digits not 6 digits exactly

i am having difficulty finding whats wrong

Comment: Just as @ellak said, `009617012345` will successfully pass because `7` is matched in `[0-9]` and the rest is exactly 6 digits.

Comment: @Passerby kindly  Check My Comment in ellak's  Answer

Comment: I'm not sure how VB.NET parses Regex, but in Chrome, the example I provided above can still pass the Regex test @burning_LEGION gave: `/((00)|(\+))961((\d)|(7[0168]))\d{6}/.test("009617012345")` returns `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this regex `((00)|(\+))961((\d)|(7[0168]))\d{6}`

Comment: Wouldn't this match any number of digits after the 961?

Comment: Kindly Check the My Comment on @ellak answer and if you could explain the diifrence

Comment: @burning_LEGION: sorry my bad. But it matches 00961x? And not 009616123456?

Comment: @ellak i miss brekets, i added it

Answer (score 1):

Ths is what I would use.

```
/^(00|\+)961(\d|7[069])\d{6}$/
```

- 00 or +
- 961
- a 1-digit number or 70 or 76 or 79
- a 6-digit number

Answer (score 1):

The `[0-9]{1}` will match also the cellular codes 7x since 7 is between 0 and 9. This means that a "5 digit cellular number" will match on a 7 and six more digits.

Comment: but the answer provided by @burning_LEGION he replaced [0-9]{1} by \d which is the same thing right  ? and it worked fine !

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 /^(00961|\+961)([0-9]|70|76|79)\d{6}$/.test( phonenumber );
//^                                    start of string
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                       00961 or +0961
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       a digit 0 to 9 or 70 or 76 or 79
//                              ^^^^^  6 digits
//                                   ^ end of string
```

Answer (score 0):

The cellar code is forming a trap, as @ellak points out:

```js
/^((00)|(\+))961((\d)|(7[0168]))\d{6}$/.test("009617612345"); // true
```

Here the code should breaks like this: `00 961 76 12345`,

but the RegEx practically breaks it like this: `00 961 7 612345`, because `7` is matched in `\d`, and the rest is combined, exactly in 6 digits, and matched.

I'm not sure if this is actually valid, but I guess this is not what you want, otherwise the RegEx in your question should work.

Here's a kinda long RegEx that avoids the trap:

```js
/^(00|\+)961([0-68-9]\d{6}|7[234579]\d{5}|7[0168]\d{6})$/
```

A few test result:

```js
/(00|\+)961([0-68-9]\d{6}|7[234579]\d{5}|7[0168]\d{6})/.test("009617012345")
  false
/(00|\+)961([0-68-9]\d{6}|7[234579]\d{5}|7[0168]\d{6})/.test("009618012345")
  true
/(00|\+)961([0-68-9]\d{6}|7[234579]\d{5}|7[0168]\d{6})/.test("009617612345")
  false
/(00|\+)961([0-68-9]\d{6}|7[234579]\d{5}|7[0168]\d{6})/.test("0096176123456")
  true
```

Answer (score 0):

Just recently, the Lebanese Ministry of Telecommunication has changed area codes on the IMS. So the current Regex matcher becomes:

```
^(00|\+)961[ -]?(2[1245789]|7[0168]|8[16]|\d)[ -]?\d{6}$
```

- Prefix: **00** OR **+**
- Country code: **961**
- Area code: 1-digit or 2-digits; including **2***, **7***, **8***..., OR a single digit for Ogero numbers on the old IMS network starting with **0***, and finally older mobile lines starting with **03**.
- The 6-digit number

[News on the961.com](https://www.the961.com/lebanon-changing-phone-codes/)